# Laravel update calculate sum many to many value

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have problem about update something in many to many relationship with calculate of the end of process.
For table example

stock_transports

[image]

stock_tranportation_details

[image]

stock_entries

[image]

stock_entry_details

[image]

if i click button of complete in system, i want to update stock_transpotation_details with sum of qty with condition same item_id and ref_code

and the result i hope like this

[image]

my progress code like this

```
foreach($stockEntry->stock_transport->details()->get() as $detail) {
     $arr[$detail->item_id.'_'.$detail->ref_code] = $detail->id;
 } 
 $total_qty = 0;
 foreach($stockEntry->details as $detail) {
     if($arr[$detail->item_id.'_'.$detail->ref_code]) {
                $total_qty += $detail->qty;
                $arr[$detail->item_id.'_'.$detail->ref_code] = [ 
                      'qty' => $total_qty,
                      'ref_code' => $detail->ref_code,
                      'item_id' => $detail->item_id 
                ];
     }
 }
```

and after that i update stock_transport_detail or just dump then got the wrong result, their just calculate one of the stock_entry_details
plese help me find the solution for the code or another way for example with mysql trigger or better logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would utilise Laravel relationships here, the beauty of those, is they don't have to work with database integers only. In your stock details class, add a relationship to the transport details. Assuming your classes is named `StockEntryDetail` and `StockTranportationDetail`.

```
class StockEntryDetail {
    public function transportDetails() {
        return $this->hasMany(StockTranportationDetail::class, 'ref_code', 'ref_code');
    }
}
```

To have respectable performance, i would index `ref_code` and 'item_id' on both tables.

```
Schema::create('stock_entry_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index(['ref_code', 'item_id']);
});

Schema::create('stock_tranportation_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index(['ref_code', 'item_id']);
});
```

Then you can optimize your code to the following. Find all StockDetails that has TransportDetails and the item_id is the same, this is done with a query for quick performance. Update the data and you are done.

```
// Eager load the relationships we are going over
$stockEntry = StockEntry::with('details.transportDetails')->find($id);

foreach ($stockEntry->details as $detail) {

    // find all with the same item_id, ref_code is done by relationship.
    $transportDetailsCount = $detail->transportDetails()->where('item_id')->count()

    // update your data
    $detail->qty = $transportDetailsCount;
    $detail->save();
}
```

Your scope and question is big and a little confusing, i think i understand and by utilizing `Laravel` features, i think the solution is cleaner and should be more manageable. In general in `Laravel` when you start to convert your models into arrays you are doing something wrong, keep the models as you can always save em to the database.

Comment: thanks for answer and good explanation @mrhn,  i think  `// update your data
    $detail->qty = $transportDetailsCount;` just update stock_entry_details but i want to update stock transportdetail, how to update stock transport detail with this relantionship

cmiiw

Comment: but then what count do you wanna put in there? your count logic seems flawed then, what does qty represent?

Comment: i wanna put sum of qty in stock_entry_details but the result wrong because the all sum of qty of stock_transport_detail not in stock_entry_details

Comment: your code its right @mrhn, my code not find the stock_tranport_id, thanks for answer and fast response

Comment: Glad it helped :)